# Using a different key name for an association attribute in rails api active model serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I am building a [Rest API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) using [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/) and [active-model-serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to easily filter the required fields in the JSON. I am also using the `has_one` association in these serializers. All I wanted to know is how do I specify a different key name for the `has_one` attribute.

That is, I have two models say: `Employee` and `Address`, and there is a `has_one :address` in  say `EmployeeSerializer`. The response that I get is:

```
{
  id: 1,
  address: {
   street: "some_street",
   city: "some_city"
  }
}
```

But I would like to get the following response:

```
{
  id: 1,
  stays: {
   street: "some_street",
   city: "some_city"
  }
}
```

I tried using `has_one :address, :key => :stays`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which version of AMS do you use? I'm not intimately familiar with the code base, but from a quick look they `key` argument seems not to have been included in all recent ones. As a workaround, try defining `has_one :stays` together with `def stays; object.address; end`.

Comment: @janfoeh I'm using the 0.9.0 version. Also I am using a different serializer for the association. i.e., `has_one :address, key: 'status', serializer: MyAddressSerializer`. It's taking the attributes from `MyAddressSerializer` but the attribute key still is `address`

Comment: Ah. If I read the [changes between 0.9.0 and 0.9.1](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/compare/v0.9.0...v0.9.1) correctly, the argument was called `embed_key` in 0.9.0, not `key`.

Comment: It's still the same. No luck! :(

Comment: Sorry, then I'm clueless as well. I use 0.8.1, and I just successfully tested `has_one :uploader, key: 'user', serializer: 'SpecialSerializer'` - both arguments work as expected.

Comment: Alright let me check with 0.8.1 version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define `stays` as one of the attributes you want to have in your json.

Naturally, the serializer will go to the model instance and not find an attribute in the model with that name. So, it will be sitting there scratching its head as to what in the world the value of `:stays` should be.

That's OK, because you can define an instance method in your serializer telling it exactly what that value should be. In that instance method, you are given `object` variable which is the object the serializer is currently processing. `object.address` therefore will be your `Address` instance.

Once you have your address instance, you can instantiate a serializer which will use that instance to display the fields outlined inside of it. I believe, `root: false` is necessary as otherwise, `:stays` attribute (or whatever the serializer gives you back in this case) will be displayed inside another `:stays` attribute.

Your final serializer for `Employee` should look as follows:

```
class EmployeeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :stays

  def stays
    MyAddressSerializer.new(object.address, root: false)
  end

end
```

Comment: Add some description to why it will do the job. Right now as the answer stands on its own. It is of very low quality and does not suit the SO Q&A style very well and has been marked as a Low Quality Post.

Comment: @Cheesebaron how is this? :)

Comment: Would this work for a `has_many` relationship that needs a `each_serializer` as well?

Comment: For a `has_many` this is what I do: `ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(object.my_has_many_assoc, each_serializer: MySerializer). Thank you @KalmanHazins!
`

Comment: For anyone trying to implement this strategy with the additional details by @swaroopsm in the latest AMS master (>=0.10.0 as of April 2016), please keep in mind that the answer posted will not work

Use this instead:

ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(object.my_has_many_assoc, each_serializer: MySerializer)

Answer (score 7):

@janfoeh is right on. I just tested this in version 0.8 and it works just fine

1. `gem "active_model_serializers", "~> 0.8.0"` in your Gemfile
2. Kill the server
3. `$bundle install`
4. `has_one :address, key: "stays"`
5. Start the server back up

Works great!

As the documentation for the gem says ([here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/master#maintenance-please-read)), "you probably want to use version 0.8"

Comment: If I use the `0.8.0` version, the `MyAddressSerializer` doesn't work in: `has_one :address, key: 'status', serializer: MyAddressSerializer`

Comment: @swaroopsm is `Address` always serialized with `MyAddressSerializer`? If yes, you can define that on `Address` itself with `def active_model_serializer; MyAddressSerializer; end`.

Comment: This worked for me using `active_model_serializers (0.10.7)`

Answer (score 0):

> From 0.10.0 as of April 2016 (thanks to @AlfredoGallegos in the comments)

The answer posted will not work for 0.10.0 +

Use this instead:

```
ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new
  (object.my_has_many_assoc, each_serializer: MySerializer)
```

Also it seems most people are moving to the [Netflix JSONAPI gem,](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) it has more support and is 25 times faster (however [please note it does not support](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/issues/289) the JSON default setting of AMS).